# Is it possible to create a duplicate UUID in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, uuid, lume

I am making UUIDs like this:

```
Uuid::uuid4();
```

and save in a database as `track id`.

Is it possible to create a duplicate UUID?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? One question is about Java, this one about php/laravel. Some answers that put the probabilities into perspective have valid information for both questions, but the true answer will take into account the quality of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a `unique` column, then you can look up the UUID from the database and save it in another record. You cannot feasibly generate a duplicate UUID using `Uuid:uuid4()` without astronomical odds, however.

If you intend to use the UUID as a unique identifier, best practice would be to also add a `unique` constraint on your database column.